# Facebook share dialog sizing bug in Firefox on Windows

Tags: facebook, firefox, share, facebook-share

We developed a website with fb share dialog to share GIF's into facebook, here is our code snippet for this feature:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'gif_480x480_px_url',
  hashtag: '#hashtag'
}, function(response) {

});
```

We use the share dialog as you can see above, because we need the response to use for a feature, anyway we tried the share.php as well (like here: http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/), but this one does not work neither unfortunately.

The bug is the following: if the user shares a GIF in Windows Firefox, the facebook's dialog pop-up will open much bigger (and without a scrollbar) than it would be necessary, and most importantly hiding the buttons on the bottom making the share literally impossible because the dialog window is not able to be resized manually. [Please see the issue on this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmfFy.jpg).

In the fb docs, there is no parameter to add max height to the window.

Huge thanks for your help to debug in advance!!!

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks, it was already done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a bug Facebook has to fix on their end.